# Xamarin.iOS - sudden error after updating Visual Studio: ibtool exited with code 72

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.Forms app, but this concerns Xamarin.iOS only.

I want to run the app on an iOS emulator, but I get an error which I cannot find on the internet. This prevents me from testing my app on iOS. This happens ever since I updated Visual Studio 2019 to version 16.9.0.

The main error is "ibtool exited with code 72", but this causes a list of errors:
[image]

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to update Xcode?

Comment: Yep. Xcode has the latest version.

Comment: Could you create a new project sucessfully?

Comment: Also yep. I can create projects, commit changes, deploy everything on App Center and everything works. Testing for Android works as well. The only thing that is not working is the testing on an iOS emulator .

Comment: Try to go into xcode  **library ->develop ->coresimulator ->device**,delete the device,and recreate a new one